# Using sbt as a library

Tags: scala, sbt

sbt has a bunch of nice utils in (e.g.) sbt IO - I'd like to use these in my app.  What are the artifact group/names/versions I should be referencing?  (This is nearly impossible to Google for...)  I looked in scala-tools.org but I could only find 2.7-compatible releases (and I'm building a 2.9 project) - am I out of luck?  (For now I might try copying the relevant sources over into my project, if they're easy enough to tease apart and to port to 2.9.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The groupId is `org.scala-sbt` as can be seen from https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/blob/0.12.1/project/Sbt.scala but apparently the latest artifacts are not available in a Maven repository. It might be best to build sbt yourself and install it into your local repository, or to just copy the source files into your project. The latest version of sbt (version 0.11) [appears to use Scala 2.9](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/blob/0.11/project/Sbt.scala).